# wordpress acf link title not displaying

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a link set up as array, not url. Using this code:

`<?php $link = get_sub_field('link');
    if( $link ): ?>
    <p><a class="button" href="<?php echo $link['url']; ?>" target="<?php echo $link['target']; ?>"><?php echo $link['title']; ?></a></p>
    <?php endif; ?>`

the page title of the link only shows on the home page "sign up" box. On other pages and in other custom fields the link href is populated but the title doesn't show.

https://sullivanlehdesigns.com/clients/andonix/testing/
There should be a link showing on the card below the text.

Results of dump on an inside page:

`array(3) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["url"]=>
  string(72) "https://sullivanlehdesigns.com/clients/andonix/sign-up-for-a-test-drive/"
  ["target"]=>
  string(0) ""
}`

and on the home page:

`array(3) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(24) "Sign up for a test drive"
  ["url"]=>
  string(72) "https://sullivanlehdesigns.com/clients/andonix/sign-up-for-a-test-drive/"
  ["target"]=>
  string(0) ""
}`

the code in the template:

```
        <?php   // check if the nested repeater field has rows of data
        if( have_rows('card_item') ): 
            // loop through the rows of data ?>
        <section class="cards">
            <?php while ( have_rows('card_item') ) : the_row(); ?>
            <div class="card">
                <?php $image = get_sub_field('image'); 
                echo '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" />'; ?>
                <h3><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></h3>
                <p><?php the_sub_field('text'); ?></p>

            <?php $link = get_sub_field('link');
                if( $link ): ?>
<p class="button"><a href="<?php echo $link['url']; ?>" target="<?php echo $link['target']; ?>"><?php echo $link['title']; ?></a></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </section>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Temporarily add `var_dump( $link )` before the `if` and see if the array items (`url`, `title`, etc.) are good. If not, then edit the ACF fields on that post/page.

Comment: I'm not sure what to edit, since the url is showing, and the title shows on the home page. Results of var_dump added to original post

Comment: Ok, thank you for sharing the `var_dump()` result. So as you could see, on the inside page, the link title is empty, which I'm not sure why so. But on the "testing" page, I couldn't find the `<p><a class="button" href...>...</a></p>` anywhere.. If you did put it there (the PHP code), the HTML should still show up despite the link title is empty. Could it be that only on the home page you set the values of the ACF field?

Comment: sorry, the "button" was specific to the footer box. I just double-checked and resaved the pages. All pages use the same template for the footer box, but only home shows the title in the link. All Pages and Posts use the same template for card content too. I added both a link array and a link url to the template to test. The link url works, using link array does not. I can set up two boxes for every link but it would be more consistent if internal links grabbed the page title automatically. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You got this on the admin 'Edit Page/Post' page, right? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/acf-link-field-interface.png So if you set the 'URL' and 'Link Text' on each Page/Post (or only the corresponding ones), then the `$link['title']` wouldn't be empty..

Comment: The only difference between that screen and what I see is the button always says "add link" not "update". I selected a page to link to, the top box is filled with the url from that choice, then I press "add link" and then "update" on the page. And they all use the same code from the same template, but it seems only the first instance will show title.

Comment: Sorry about the `get_the_ID()` thing. I forgot you're using `get_sub_field()` and not `get_field()`.. so I'm not sure why the other instances have the `$link['title']` empty, but if you could show the entire ACF loop (i.e. `have_rows()`, which I supposed you used it?), then I might be able to help you further.

Comment: edited original post to show code on the template

Comment: Thanks for the update. The code is good as I could see it. And after all, it's the exact same code that you use on the home page, right? After you edit the link URL and title on the back-end, did the link (title) get changed successfully? Try linking to another page.

Comment: I can add to the "link text" field and that shows, but if I just choose a site page, only the home page automatically adds the title as "link text". Choosing a different page has no effect. This is fine for me, but it's a concern for content editors in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to change the "Return Value" of the Link Sub Field in the back end from "Link URL" to "Link Array"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZF9z.png)